powershell could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json
I wrote a powershell script and it runs fine with visual studio code, but when i run the script outside visual studio code i get an error message (see image).
Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Does it work if you use PowerShell 7 (pwsh.exe instead of powershell.exe)?

Hi I don’t have powershell 7 installed on my computer.

You sorta do even if you didn't install it directly - the PowerShell Extension for vscode comes with the latest version of PowerShell (7.4 as of writing), so if your code appears to "just work" in vscode => it'll probably work in pwsh.exe

PowerShell 5 uses an older version of Newtonsoft.Json, so there's an assembly dependency conflict. Try downgrading the version of Selenium that you're using - try 4.3 at first, and if that doesn't work then it might be a bit of trial and error to find a version that does.

I solved the problem by importing the latest Newtonsoft dll into my PowerShell project. ' Import-Module "$($workingPath)\Newtonsoft.json.dll" '
